# Does calling docker-compose down before docker-compose build change anything?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Trying to determine if calling

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

is the same as:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

I have looked and can't find anything specific. I know docker-compose down removes containers and networks docker-compose build creates the services. So I am not sure if down is an unnecessary extra step or not.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose build` creates the images, which are used by `docker-compose up` to create containers. It's during the `docker-compose up` step in which networks are created as well. Multiple containers (which are effectively, a running instance of the image) can be created from one image.

If no changes are made to the files in the build environment, or the steps in the Dockerfile, running a `build` will not create a new image.

Regardless, building the images while containers are running should not affect running containers, since the newly-built image will be named differently (see for yourself, with `docker image ls`) and the running container will still be running off of the old image.

To answer your question then, possibly: if the steps in the Dockerfile changed, or the files in the build environment changed, etc. before you call `build` then the image will be rebuilt and the new container created by `docker-compose up` will be run from the new image.

Otherwise, if none of those changed, calling `build` will do nothing, and `up` will also do nothing (provided the containers are still running)